# ionic framework(angular) - How to decode QR code image?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, qr-code

I am using ionic framework v3. I am tryingto decode qr code image selected from gallery.

I tried using [link](https://github.com/zxing-js/library) but it mostly not decoding.

I did linke :

```
 const codeReader = new BrowserQRCodeReader();
    codeReader.decodeFromImage(undefined, imgData).then((result: any) => {
      console.log(result); 
    }).catch((err:any) => {
     console.log(err);
    });
```

I am passing base64 image data.

can anyone suggest best way to decode image from gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use base64 data directly with the `decodeFromImage` method but need to provide a URL to your image. How you get the URL depends on the plugin you use for letting the user pick the image.

If you only have base64 data you could instead add a hidden `img` element to your page and use the base64 data as its `src` attribute. Then use `decodeFromImage()` with this `img` element as first parameter.

Comment: thanks for your answer i will try and let you know.